# Make deleted posts available via link

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I have asked some questions that I want to delete but link to from another place. However, as apparent from what I've found, other people can't view deleted posts even by link. Please make them viewable via links or, if they are, clarify that.

Comment: This will not be implemented. Do note that if you really want to save a copy of a page before you delete it, the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) can help. Licensing could be an issue, usage is at your own risk.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to its original request. If you want to request something else, make a new post. You can do so without deleting this one first, so there's also no need for all the comments discussing deleting the answer your edits invalidated so you can post a different request.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I already knew that, but I want to delete this question anyway

Comment: You can not delete answered questions, as you are already aware. I'm not sure why you think misbehaviour like vandalizing the title is going to get this post deleted, that's not how moderation on SE works. I recommend you stop before we have to resort to step 2 from the  'Enforcement' section at [/help/conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Why would you do that? I don't seem to have broken any of the rules there

Answer (score 12):

The whole point of soft deletion is well - so random users coming across the site can't see it. That users can see their own posts was added in later (because it's your post), and 10k users pretty much have nearly moderator level trust.

The appropriate help center entries for [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) and [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) cover who can see deleted posts so its quite clarified.

If you absolutely need to share a deleted post, just take a screenshot and share that.

Comment: Why can't you use robots.txt so that search engines don't index it, but you can view it via a link, so random users coming across the site can't see it, but users coming from the link can?

Comment: @Orisphera you confuse deleted with private. If there was a "private post" concept in Stack Exchange (there isn't) then you would have a point, and link would be expected. But something that was deleted, is not meant to be seen anymore.

Comment: @Orisphera deleted posts generally fall into a category of a post not suitable for the site. Do you have a deleted post you feel shouldn’t have been deleted?

Comment: Well - its mentioned that they want to delete their own posts themselves so that's possibly not the case there.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard But I can see deleted questions that I wrote. I think you should rename deleting to privating.

Comment: @Orisphera as others tried to explain, the fact we can see our deleted posts is a "bonus" that wasn't originally part of the system. It's meant for us to edit the post and maybe salvage it, leading to it being undeleted. It was never meant for others to see it. (without enough reputation.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I think this “bonus” makes it incorrect to call them “deleted” anymore